# Querying on Bigquery repeated fields

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Below is the schema of my BigQuery table. I am selecting the sentence_id, store and BU_model and inserting data into another table in BigQuery. The datatypes for the new table generated are integer, repeated and repeated respectively.
I want to flatten/unnest the repeated fields so that they are created as STRING fields in my second table. How could this be achieved using standard sql?

```
+- sentences: record (repeated)
|  |- sentence_id: integer                                                                                                                             
|  |- autodetected_language: string                                                                                                                    
|  |- processed_language: string 
|  +- attributes: record
|  |  |- agent_rating: integer
|  |  |- store: string (repeated)
|  +- classifications: record
|  |  |- BU_Model: string (repeated)
```

The query that I am using to create the second table is as below. I would want to query on the BU_Model as a STRING column.

```
SELECT sentence_id ,a.attributes.store,a.classifications.BU_Model
FROM staging_table , unnest(sentences) a
```

Expected Output should look like:

**Staging table:**

```
41783851    regions     Apparel
            district    Footwear
12864656    regions
            district
```

**Final Target Table:**

```
41783851    regions     Apparel
41783851    regions     Footwear            
41783851    district    Apparel
41783851    district    Footwear
12864656    regions
12864656    district
```

I tried the below query and it seems to work as expected, but this means that i would have to unnest every expected repeated field. My table in Bigquery has 50+ columns which are repeated. Is there a easier way around this ?

```
SELECT
sentence_id,
flattened_stores,
flattened_Model
FROM `staging`  
left join unnest(sentences) a
left join unnest(a.attributes.store) as flattened_stores
left join unnest(a.classifications.BU_Model) as flattened_Model
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want still three columns in your output - with arrays being flattened into string

```
SELECT sentence_id , 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(a.attributes.store, ',') store,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(a.classifications.BU_Model, ',') BU_Model
FROM staging_table , unnest(sentences) a
```

> UPDATE to address recent changes in question

In BigQuery Standard SQL - use of `LEFT JOIN UNNEST()` (as you did in your last query) is the most reasonable way to do what you want to get as a result

In BigQuery Legacy SQL - you can use `FLATTEN` syntax - but it has same drawback of needing to repeat same for all 50+ column

Very simplified example:

```
#legacySQL
SELECT sentence_id, store, BU_Model
FROM (FLATTEN([project:dataset.stage], BU_Model))
```

Conclusion: I would go with `LEFT JOIN UNNEST()` approach

Comment: Hi Mikhail- I just edited my question on the expected output

Comment: your expected output makes not much sense to me as it does cross joining of values in store and in model - please clarify/confirm it is exactly what you want

Comment: especially cross joining of columns will be a problem for 50+ columns. I feel you should reconsider your design/requirements

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I agree on the 50+ columns being a problem in the join, the only approach would be to split the key and repeated column into different tables and then join them as per use-case of the business. For now since the ask is just 2, we are good with the above approach.

Comment: makes  sense :o)